# How to customize Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

I want to customize some settings in my *daftar isi* (table of contents). [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_3_zMgL2l7s2bOI8VtCEwhhxiy0KBC_l/view?usp=sharing) is the current sample .pdf output file, containing the full list of my table of contents.

What I want to customize is:

1. Omitting `. . . . . . . . . . .`  **ONLY** in `ABSTRAK, ABSTRACT, DAFTAR ISI, DAFTAR TABEL, DAFTAR GAMBAR, DAFTAR ALGORITME, DAFTAR LAMPIRAN, BAB 1 PENDAHULUAN, BAB 2 LANDASAN TEORI, BAB 3 METODOLOGI PENELITIAN, BAB 4 IMPLEMENTASI DAN PENGUJIAN, BAB 5 KESIMPULAN DAN SARAN`.
2. For these section, which is actually not a `BAB`, but `LAMPIRAN` (*bab* = chapter, *lampiran* = appendix in English):
   [image]
   I want to change the text `BAB`  to `LAMPIRAN`.

I think I have to change something in `.sty` file and my `index` file. But unfortunately, I am not able to find what to change yet. Below is the code for:

1. `if_ithb.sty`, which is a Style file used by my uni to generate thesis reports.

```
% Mengatur bahasa latex
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Untuk pengaturan spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

% Untuk mengatur level section 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

% Digunakan untuk memasukan gambar ke laporan. 
\usepackage{graphicx}

% Untuk mengatur spacing antara paragraf
\usepackage{parskip}

% Membuat indent
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parindent{1.5cm}

% Untuk mengkustomisasi margin
\usepackage{scrextend}

% Untuk mengatur header dan footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% Membuat seluruh tulisan menjadi Times New Roman. 
\usepackage{pslatex}

% Merubah numbering chapter dan section untuk judul setiap bab menggunakan romawi dan judul anak bab menggunakan arabic
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}\hspace{0,3cm}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}\hspace{-0,35cm}}

% Merubah huruf kapital pada judul daftar isi, daftar gambar, dan daftar table
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfil\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{BAB }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\bfseries BAB 1 :\ } % if more than 9 chapters, use "Chapter 10"
\cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}

% Mengatur font section
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}

% Untuk merupakan format penulisan BAB
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\doublespacing\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}\filcenter}      {0.15cm}{\centering\uppercase}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-1cm}{20pt}

% Mengatur spacing section
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pt}{0pt}{-0.05cm}
    
% Digunakan untuk mengatur caption dalam dokumen.
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=up]{caption}

% Untuk menghapus titik dua (colon)
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=space}

% Mengatur nomor caption gambar
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

% Mengatur nomor caption table
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}

% Mengatur Hyphenation pada latex
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

% Untuk mengatur setting indent
\setlength\parindent{1.30cm}

% Untuk memasukkan table
\usepackage{tabularx}

% Untuk mengatur width
\usepackage{changepage}

% Menggatur setting halaman 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  left=4cm,            % <-- you want to adjust this
  top=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  bottom=3cm,
}

% Teks testing
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Untuk mengatur subscript supscript
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

% Untuk mengatur wrap picture
\usepackage{wrapfig}

% Untuk notasi matematika
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

% untuk mengatur label nomor pada rumus
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}

% Untuk mengatur spacing daftar gambar
\newcommand*{\noaddvspace}{\renewcommand*{\addvspace}[1]{}}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\noaddvspace}

%untuk mengatur package include table in excel
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% untuk mengatur landscape page
\usepackage{rotating}
```

2. `index.tex`, which is the main page for my document.

```
% Tipe dokumen adalah report dengan satu kolom. 
% Mengatur setting halaman 
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% Hyperlink untuk section, link, citation 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=green,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Load konfigurasi LaTeX untuk tipe laporan thesis ITHB
\usepackage{if_ithb}

% Konfigurasi package lainnya
\usepackage[chapter,Algoritme,ruled]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% Untuk break algorithm biar ga offside
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
{% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
        \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
        \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
            {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
            \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
            \else % #1 is not \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
            \fi
            \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
        }
    }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
        \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

% Daftar Lampiran
\newcommand\listappendixname{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
   \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother

% Daftar Pseudocode - Algoritme
\makeatletter
\def
\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{ALGORITME} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{DAFTAR \uppercase{\ALG@name}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}

\tcbset{colback=white!10!white,colframe=black!50!black, highlight math style= {enhanced,colframe=black,colback=black!10!white,boxsep=0pt}}

% Daftar pemenggalan suku kata dan istilah dalam LaTeX
\include{hype.indonesia}

% Variabel baru untuk menyimpan nomor halaman
\newcounter{originalpagenumber}%
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%

% Daftar isi, supaya subsubsection terindeks juga
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Set custom font family
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\setcellgapes{5pt}

% Awal bagian penulisan laporan
\begin{document}

    % Sampul Laporan
    \include{sampul_luar}
    
    % Sampul Laporan - dalam
    \include{sampul_dalam}
    
    % Daftar isi, gambar, dan tabel
    % Gunakan penomeran Romawi (i, ii, iii, ...) setelah bagian ini.
%    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
%    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%    \makeatletter

    \newcounter{savepage}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    % Halaman Penyataan Orisinalitas
%   \include{halaman_pernyataan_orisinalitas}
    
    % Halaman Pengesahan
    % \include{halaman_pengesahan}
    
    % Halaman Publikasi
    %\include{halaman_publikasi}
 
    % Lembar Abstrak
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRAK}
    \include{abstrak}

    % Lembar Abstract
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
    \include{abstract}

    % Kata Pengantar
%   \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{KATA PENGANTAR}
    %\include{kata_pengantar}
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
    \listoffigures
    
    \clearpage
    {
        \let
        \oldnumberline
        \numberline
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{Pseudocode~\oldnumberline}
    }
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ALGORITME}
    \renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{DAFTAR ALGORITME}
    \lhead{\emph{DAFTAR ALGORITME}}
    {
        \let
        \oldnumberline
        \numberline
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algoritme~\oldnumberline}
        \listofalgorithms
    }
    
%   \clearpage
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
    \listofappendices
    \clearpage
    
    \setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
    \makeatletter
    \def\MyPagenumbering#1{%
        \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\arabic{chapter}-\csname @#1\endcsname
            \c@page}}
    \makeatother
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{BAB \thechapter \ #1}{}}
    
    \fancyhf{}
    % Gunakan penomeran Arab (1, 2, 3, ...) setelah bagian ini.
    \MyPagenumbering{arabic}
    
    % Untuk mengatur posisi pagenumber
    %\pagestyle{plain}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \fill
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
    \lhead{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \fancyhf{}%
        \fancyfoot[R]{\arabic{chapter}-1}%
    }
    
    \onehalfspacing
    \rfoot{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
    
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab1}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab2}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab3}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab4}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab5}

    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \fancyhf{}%
        \fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}%
    }
    \rfoot{\thepage}

    % Daftar Pustaka
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR REFERENSI}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR REFERENSI}
    \include{pustaka}
    \cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}
    
    % Lampiran 
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
        \markboth{LAMPIRAN \thechapter \ #1}{}}
        
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}-\arabic{table}}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\Alph{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
    
    \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{LAMPIRAN }
    
    \begin{appendix}
        \include{lampiran}
        \rfoot{\Alph{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
    \end{appendix}
    
\end{document}
```

What should I modify to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To remove dots from the contents page, add the following command to your preamble:

   `\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}`

**UPDATE:**

To remove dots from particular entry in ToC, you can try the trick:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{10000}}
```

This will write `\def\@dotsep{10000}` into the ToC file and from that point on the dots are gone.

To have the dots again at a later point issue

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{4.5}}
```

2. To change the text `BAB` to `LAMPIRAN` add the following to your preamble:

```
   \setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}
    
    \let\oldappendix\appendix
    \renewcommand{\appendix}{%
      \oldappendix
      \addtocontents{toc} 
        {\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{LAMPIRAN }}
    }
```

The updated `index.tex` with the above corrections is as follows:

```
% Tipe dokumen adalah report dengan satu kolom. 
% Mengatur setting halaman 
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, onecolumn, oneside, final]{report}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}

\usepackage{tabto}
\newenvironment{tabs}[1]
{\TabPositions{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable}  
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

% Hyperlink untuk section, link, citation 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=green,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue
}

% Load konfigurasi LaTeX untuk tipe laporan thesis ITHB
\usepackage{if_ithb}


%---- code for appendix---------

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}% Just for this example

\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \oldappendix
  \addtocontents{toc} 
    {\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{LAMPIRAN }}
}

%------------

% Untuk break algorithm biar ga offside
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{breakablealgorithm}
{% \begin{breakablealgorithm}
    \begin{center}
        \refstepcounter{algorithm}% New algorithm
        \hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt% \@fs@pre for \@fs@ruled
        \renewcommand{\caption}[2][\relax]{% Make a new \caption
            {\raggedright\textbf{\fname@algorithm~\thealgorithm} ##2\par}%
            \ifx\relax##1\relax % #1 is \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##2}%
            \else % #1 is not \relax
            \addcontentsline{loa}{algorithm}{\protect\numberline{\thealgorithm}##1}%
            \fi
            \kern2pt\hrule\kern2pt
        }
    }{% \end{breakablealgorithm}
        \kern2pt\hrule\relax% \@fs@post for \@fs@ruled
    \end{center}
}
\makeatother

% Daftar Lampiran
\newcommand\listappendixname{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
\newcommand\appcaption[1]{%
   \addcontentsline{app}{chapter}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
   \chapter*{\listappendixname}\@starttoc{app}}
\makeatother

% Daftar Pseudocode - Algoritme
\makeatletter
\def
\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\renewcommand{\ALG@name}{ALGORITME} 
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{DAFTAR \uppercase{\ALG@name}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{algorithm}} 
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}

\tcbset{colback=white!10!white,colframe=black!50!black, highlight math style= {enhanced,colframe=black,colback=black!10!white,boxsep=0pt}}

% Daftar pemenggalan suku kata dan istilah dalam LaTeX
\include{hype.indonesia}

% Variabel baru untuk menyimpan nomor halaman
\newcounter{originalpagenumber}%
\renewcommand\cftchapdotsep{\cftdotsep}%

% Daftar isi, supaya subsubsection terindeks juga
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

% Set custom font family
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\fontfamily{zi4}\selectfont,
}
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{cmtt}

\setcellgapes{5pt}

% Awal bagian penulisan laporan
\begin{document}

    % Sampul Laporan
    \include{sampul_luar}
    
    % Sampul Laporan - dalam
    \include{sampul_dalam}
    
    % Daftar isi, gambar, dan tabel
    % Gunakan penomeran Romawi (i, ii, iii, ...) setelah bagian ini.
%    \captionsetup{justification=centering}
%    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%    \makeatletter

    \newcounter{savepage}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    % Halaman Penyataan Orisinalitas
%   \include{halaman_pernyataan_orisinalitas}
    
    % Halaman Pengesahan
    % \include{halaman_pengesahan}
    
    % Halaman Publikasi
    %\include{halaman_publikasi}
    %
    \addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{10000}}
    %
    % Lembar Abstrak
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRAK}
    \include{abstrak}

    % Lembar Abstract
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
    \include{abstract}

    % Kata Pengantar
%   \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{KATA PENGANTAR}
    %\include{kata_pengantar}
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ISI}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR TABEL}
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
    
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR GAMBAR}
    \listoffigures
    
    \clearpage
    {
        \let
        \oldnumberline
        \numberline
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{Pseudocode~\oldnumberline}
    }
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR ALGORITME}
    \renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{DAFTAR ALGORITME}
    \lhead{\emph{DAFTAR ALGORITME}}
    {
        \let
        \oldnumberline
        \numberline
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{Algoritme~\oldnumberline}
        \listofalgorithms
    }
   
    \vspace*{-2.5cm}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR LAMPIRAN}
    \listofappendices
%--------------- 
    \addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{4.5}} 
%--------------------------
    \clearpage
        
    \setcounter{savepage}{\arabic{page}}
    \makeatletter
    \def\MyPagenumbering#1{%
        \global\c@page \@ne \gdef\thepage{\arabic{chapter}-\csname @#1\endcsname
            \c@page}}
    \makeatother
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
        \markboth{BAB \thechapter \ #1}{}}
    
    \fancyhf{}
    % Gunakan penomeran Arab (1, 2, 3, ...) setelah bagian ini.
    \MyPagenumbering{arabic}
    
    % Untuk mengatur posisi pagenumber
    %\pagestyle{plain}
    \setlength\LTleft{0pt}            % default: \fill
    \setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill
    \lhead{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
    
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \fancyhf{}%
        \fancyfoot[R]{\arabic{chapter}-1}%
    }
    
    \onehalfspacing
    \rfoot{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
    
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab1}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab2}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab3}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab4}

    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \include{bab5}

    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{\thesavepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
        \fancyhf{}%
        \fancyfoot[c]{\thepage}%
    }
    \rfoot{\thepage}

    % Daftar Pustaka
    \renewcommand{\bibname}{DAFTAR REFERENSI}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{DAFTAR REFERENSI}
    \include{pustaka}
    \cftsetindents{chap}{0pt}{\mylen}
    
%     \clearpage

    % Lampiran 
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{
        \markboth{LAMPIRAN \thechapter \ #1}{}}
        
    \pagenumbering{arabic} 
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\Alph{chapter}-\arabic{table}}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\Alph{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
    
    \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{LAMPIRAN }
  
    \begin{appendix}
%     \renewcommand{\chaptername}{LAMPIRAN}
    %----------- 
    \include{lampiran}
    %---------------------------
    \rfoot{\Alph{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
    \end{appendix}
  
\end{document}
```

The contents of a sample appendix file `lampiran.tex` is given below:

```
\appendix

\chapter{Nomor Not MIDI, Nama Not}

\chapter{Hasil Pengukian Arsitektur}
```

[image]

Comment: ```\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}``` works, but it omits all the dots in ToC. I do not want to omit  them in ```BAB 1, BAB 2, BAB 3, BAB 4, BAB 5, DAFTAR REFERENSI,  LAMPIRAN``` (please refer to my attached sample output file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_3_zMgL2l7s2bOI8VtCEwhhxiy0KBC_l/view?usp=sharing)). Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Also, the ```BAB``` is still not changed to ```LAMPIRAN``` at my ToC. By using ```\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{Chapter }```, it all changed to ```Chapter```, including the ```BAB```. If this does not bother you, may you please update the answer? Thank you.

Comment: @DionisiusPratama I have added few corrections and updated the answer.

Comment: ```\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\cftdotsep{10000}``` worked nicely, thank you! Also, the ```LAMPIRAN``` is now successfully changed. One last thing, how to reduce extra tab in ```BAB 1 PENDAHULUAN, BAB 2 LANDASAN TEORI, BAB 3 METODOLOGI PENELITIAN, ```? I think the tab is too far @Tanvir

Comment: I've got it. I can just comment the ```\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{7em}``` line.